# Display Flex not working to show Horizontal Nav links

Tags: html, css

```
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="your-logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

```
header .nav-links ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* Ensure the direction is horizontal */
}

header .nav-links li {
    margin-right: 20px; /* Add margin to space out the links horizontally */
}


header .nav-links a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I am having a problem with my navigation bar as it is showing a vertical intead of horizontal link. I am using a design flex on  I also tried using inline block on

and it works as expected. I just dont understand why flex is not working to show Horizontal links..

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the selector. Originally, it looked for a list as a children of a `nav-links` class

```
header .nav-links ul
```

But `nav-links` is the actual class name of the list, so it needs to be like this:

```
header ul.nav-links
```

```css
header ul.nav-links { /* <<<<< NOTE THIS CHANGE */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header .nav-links li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header .nav-links a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="your-logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to the `flex` and check for conflicting styles, and give it some li some dimensions

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. Taking time to clarify what you mean by adding li dimensions would improve the quality of you answer and be more helpful for people reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector to style the ul is wrong:
Instead of **header .nav-links ul** should be **header .nav-links** or **header ul.nav-links**

- **header .nav-links ul**: It references the ul child of .nav-links(which doesn't exist)
- **header ul.nav-links**: It references the ul that have class nav-links

**Try the code fixed below:**

```css
header .nav-links {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* Ensure the direction is horizontal */
}

header .nav-links li {
    margin-right: 20px; /* Add margin to space out the links horizontally */
}


header .nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="your-logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to flex the `a`s within the `li`s

You want to flex the `li`s within the `.nav-links`

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    & li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 20px;
        & a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
}
```